# PHP variable with back tick return me NULL value

Tags: php, variables, shell-exec

I have  this code:

```
    <?php
    $my_var= `<script>
    </script>`;

dd($my_var);
```

as a result, I got that `$my_var` is **NULL** which is not. How I can solve the problem... I know I can use a single or double quote but I don't want that.

I also disable `shell_exec` from PHP settings...

How to solve the problem? All I need is to get the string variable...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? To create a string with backticks in it?

Comment: Are you concerned about using single and double quotes because your full string contains both of those already? Backticks aren't a substitute for any other kind of quote, and disabling shell_exec won't change that.

Comment: yes, I have big string - HTML code with single and double quotes so I need to put that html as a string and I found that backtick is the best solution because I dont need to escape any quote ...

Comment: Wherever you've found that isn't explaining things properly - backticks are a very different thing from other quotes, and not a solution for this problem. You might find [heredoc or nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) useful.

Comment: Use [Nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to avoid issues with possible interpretation of `$` in the HTML as a PHP variable.